# How to check user input in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a column input named Address, and how to check, if user input like null, 'null' and '' , the return response will be error. I have make it, but it not working.

This is my code:

```
      $address = $request->input('address');
        if ($address == null) 
        {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'no data','success'=>0]);
        }
        elseif($address == '')
        {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'no data','success'=>0]);
        }
        elseif($address == 'null')
        {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'no data','success'=>0]);
        }
        else 
         //process
        }
```

Comment: _Not working_ Exactly how is it not working? Thats not really a very good description of a problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly when i am trying to put null in address input, else process will running, it's same for 'null'

Comment: How exactly do you put "null" in that input? Are you sure that the given code is really executed? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the **empty** function, which would return FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE. This implies the following conditions considered as empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)

Snippet for your reference:

```
$address = $request->input('address');
if(empty($address)){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'no data','success' => 0]);
}
```

Comment: Why should one try that? Please add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it

Comment: empty would return FALSE if variable exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE, http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Please add all such information to the answer, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for your suggestion, it really helps the world to learn the stuffs around. Hoping that I was able to explain my answer .

Answer (score 6):

Check out laravel validation: [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation).

For example:

```
$request->validate([
     'address' => 'required'
])
```

If you want to check if input is filled you can do this:

```
$request->filled('address')
```

Check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input) for Retriving inputs.

in your case:

```
  if(!$request->filled('address')){
    return response()->json(['message'=>'no data','success'=>0]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel Validation, for more information checkout laravel doc [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'address' => 'required'
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()->first()], 422);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use validation facades :  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function MyFunction(Request $request){
  try {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'address' => 'required',
                ]
            );

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $response=array('status'=>'error','errors'=>implode(',', $validator->errors()->all()));
                return response()->json($response, 400);
            }else{

                  // validation success                   

            }

 } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response=array('status'=>'error','result'=>0,'errors'=>'Internal Server Error');
            return response()->json($response, 500);
        }
    }
}
```